# This (seemingly simple) question has no answers. Did I ask it badly? I'd like some advice

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, asking-questions

When I first joined this SE, I struggled to get answers to anything. I think I'm most of the way over the learning curve and getting solid insights here (as I do everywhere else because SE has amazing users). However, there is [one question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/324243/programmatically-add-images-to-a-post-that-i-just-added-to-the-media-library) which feels like a newbie thing that should have a simple answer. It has zero. (That said, my Google-fu has failed me on this one)

Can anyone tell me, have I asked [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/324243/programmatically-add-images-to-a-post-that-i-just-added-to-the-media-library) poorly? Should I reword it? Or have I been unlucky (and just need to wait for a little longer)?

**Edit**: Following the guidance in the comments, I have come to see that I asked very poorly. As such, I have substantially re-written the question taking out needless cruft and focusing only on the problem itself without excessive context.

Comment: In all honesty I had to read it several times to figure out what you meant, and I'm still unsure what you're trying to do in that question, IMO your question focuses a lot on your solution to the problem but nobody ever got what the original problem was, so it wasn't possible to really understand what you're trying to do or why. Instead, state your original problem, then put your attempted solution as a follow up. Otherwise it falls into the XY Problem class of questions

Comment: Right, I'd better take a fresh look at it. Thaks.